# Java XML DOM write new information without overriding previous information

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am trying to build a calendar, I'd like to have all the appointments store in a XML file, however, I can't seem to find how to do this. I've been reading answers to people with similar questions but nothing seems to work, here is the DOM Class I have, all input from "createDocument" method come from textboxes:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.*;


public class GeneradorDOM {
    private Document doc;


    public GeneradorDOM() throws ParserConfigurationException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factoria = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factoria.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = builder.newDocument();
    }


    public void createDocument(String hour, int day, int month, int year, String name,
                               String lastName, String title, String description,String row, String column) throws IOException{

        Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
        Element appointment = doc.createElement("appointment");

/* Instead of root,  I have tried with the following code as well:
        Element appointments = doc.createElement("appointments");
        doc.appendChild(appointments);

        Element appointment = doc.createElement("appointment");
        appointments.appendChild(appointment);
*/

        Element nameElement = doc.createElement("name");
        Text nameText = doc.createTextNode(name);
        appointment.appendChild(nameElement);
        nameElement.appendChild(nameText);
        appointment.appendChild(nameElement);

        Element lastNameElement = doc.createElement("lastname");
        Text lastNameText = doc.createTextNode(lastName);
        appointment.appendChild(lastNameElement);
        lastNameElement.appendChild(lastNameText);
        appointment.appendChild(lastNameElement);

        Element dayElement = doc.createElement("day");
        Text dayText = doc.createTextNode(Integer.toString(day));
        appointment.appendChild(dayElement);
        dayElement.appendChild(dayText);


        Element monthElement = doc.createElement("month");
        Text monthText = doc.createTextNode(Integer.toString(month));
        appointment.appendChild(monthElement);
        monthElement.appendChild(monthText);

        Element yearElement = doc.createElement("year");
        Text yearText = doc.createTextNode(Integer.toString(year));
        appointment.appendChild(yearElement);
        yearElement.appendChild(yearText);

        Element hourElement = doc.createElement("hour");
        Text hourText = doc.createTextNode(hour);
        appointment.appendChild(hourElement);
        hourElement.appendChild(hourText);



        Element titleElement = doc.createElement("title");
        Text titleText = doc.createTextNode(title);
        appointment.appendChild(titleElement);
        titleElement.appendChild(titleText);

        Element descriptionElement = doc.createElement("description");
        Text descriptionText = doc.createTextNode(description);
        appointment.appendChild(descriptionElement);
        descriptionElement.appendChild(descriptionText);

        Element rowElement = doc.createElement("row");
        Text rowText = doc.createTextNode(row);
        appointment.appendChild(rowElement);
        rowElement.appendChild(rowText);

        Element columnElement = doc.createElement("column");
        Text columnText = doc.createTextNode(column);
        appointment.appendChild(columnElement);
        columnElement.appendChild(columnText);

        root.appendChild(appointment);

    }

    public void generateXML() throws TransformerConfigurationException, IOException, TransformerException{
        TransformerFactory factoria = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = factoria.newTransformer();

        Source source = new DOMSource(doc);
        File file = new File("Appointments.xml");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream("Appointments.xml", true));

        transformer.transform(source, result);

    }
}
```

Comment: You are _writing_ an xml from scratch. So your resulting xml will only ever have 1 appointment. Depending on how you _read_ the document you should either parse the xml and update it, or you should pass a collection of appointments to create.

Comment: How may I do that? I have been looking for quite some hours on the internet and different forums but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good place to start, basically you can not create a empty xml and read and parse into a DOM object because you will see an exception.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Calendar;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class PersisterAppointment {

    private static String APPOINTMENT_FILE_NAME = "Appointments.xml"; 

    public static void main(String args[]){
        PersisterAppointment demo = new PersisterAppointment();
        try {
            demo.persistAppointment("Edgard","Rendón",Calendar.getInstance(),"Title field","Description field","row field","column field");
            demo.persistAppointment("Brandon","Ramirez",Calendar.getInstance(),"Title field","Description field","row field","column field");
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | TransformerException | SAXException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public boolean isAppointment(){
        File file = new File(APPOINTMENT_FILE_NAME);
        return file.exists();
    }

    public void persistAppointment(String iname, String ilastname, Calendar calendar, String ititle, String idescription, String irow, String icolumn) throws ParserConfigurationException, TransformerException, SAXException, IOException{
        DocumentBuilderFactory docfactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docbuilder = docfactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc;

        if(isAppointment()){
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(APPOINTMENT_FILE_NAME);
            doc = docbuilder.parse(is);
        }else{
            doc = docbuilder.newDocument();
        }

        TransformerFactory tfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tfactory.newTransformer();


        Source source = new DOMSource(doc);
        File file = new File(APPOINTMENT_FILE_NAME);


        Element appointment = doc.createElement("appointment");
        doc.appendChild(appointment);


        Element ename = doc.createElement("name");
        Element elastname = doc.createElement("lastname");
        Element eday = doc.createElement("day");
        Element emonth = doc.createElement("month");
        Element eyear = doc.createElement("year");
        Element ehour = doc.createElement("hour");
        Element etitle = doc.createElement("title");
        Element edescription = doc.createElement("description");
        Element erow = doc.createElement("row");
        Element ecolumn = doc.createElement("column");

        Text tname = doc.createTextNode(iname);
        Text tlastname = doc.createTextNode(ilastname);
        Text tday = doc.createTextNode(String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
        Text tmonth = doc.createTextNode(String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)));
        Text tyear = doc.createTextNode(String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)));
        Text thour = doc.createTextNode(String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)));
        Text ttitle = doc.createTextNode(ititle);
        Text tdescription = doc.createTextNode(idescription);
        Text trow = doc.createTextNode(irow);
        Text tcolumn = doc.createTextNode(icolumn);


        ename.appendChild(tname);
        elastname.appendChild(tlastname);
        eday.appendChild(tday);
        emonth.appendChild(tmonth);
        eyear.appendChild(tyear);
        ehour.appendChild(thour);
        etitle.appendChild(ttitle);
        edescription.appendChild(tdescription);
        erow.appendChild(trow);
        ecolumn.appendChild(tcolumn);

        appointment.appendChild(ename);
        appointment.appendChild(elastname);
        appointment.appendChild(eday);
        appointment.appendChild(emonth);
        appointment.appendChild(eyear);
        appointment.appendChild(ehour);
        appointment.appendChild(etitle);
        appointment.appendChild(edescription);
        appointment.appendChild(erow);
        appointment.appendChild(ecolumn);

        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);

            transformer.transform(source, result);
        }
    }
}
```

You only need to adapt the code to add a new nodes in the existing xml file

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this is to be able to serialize / deserialize an entire collection of appointments.

Wrap the information in some Pojo.

Create methods to transform Pojos to Document and back.

Then create a service which can serialze deserialize pojo into xml.

The following is a crude implementation, but it works as an example.
As a side note: using JAXB or Jackson will do this in very few lines of code.

#### Item entity

```java
package examples;

public class Appointment {
    private String hour;
    private int day;
    private int month;
    private int year;
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String row;
    private String column;

    public Appointment() {
    }

    public Appointment(String hour, int day, int month, int year, String name, String lastName, String title,
            String description, String row, String column) {
        super();
        this.hour = hour;
        this.day = day;
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
    }

    public String getHour() {
        return hour;
    }
    public void setHour(String hour) {
        this.hour = hour;
    }
    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }
    public void setDay(int day) {
        this.day = day;
    }
    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }
    public void setMonth(int month) {
        this.month = month;
    }
    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }
    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getRow() {
        return row;
    }
    public void setRow(String row) {
        this.row = row;
    }
    public String getColumn() {
        return column;
    }
    public void setColumn(String column) {
        this.column = column;
    }

}
```

#### Container entity

```java
public class UserCalendar {

    private List<Appointment> appointments = new ArrayList<Appointment>();

    public UserCalendar() {
    }

    public List<Appointment> getAppointments() {
        return appointments;
    }

    public void add(Appointment appointment) {
        appointments.add(appointment);
    }

    public Document serialize() throws ParserConfigurationException {

        Document doc = newDoc();
        Element appElms = doc.createElement("appointments");
        doc.appendChild(appElms);

        for (Appointment app : appointments) {
            Element child = addEmptyNode(appElms, "appointment");
            addValueNode(child, "name", app.getName());
            addValueNode(child, "lastname", app.getLastName());
            addValueNode(child, "day", app.getDay());
            addValueNode(child, "month", app.getMonth());
            addValueNode(child, "year", app.getYear());
            addValueNode(child, "hour", app.getHour());
            addValueNode(child, "title", app.getTitle());
            addValueNode(child, "description", app.getDescription());
            addValueNode(child, "row", app.getRow());
            addValueNode(child, "column", app.getColumn());
        }
        return doc;
    }

    private Element addValueNode(Element appointment, String name, Object value) {
        Element child = addEmptyNode(appointment, name);
        child.setTextContent(value.toString());
        return child;
    }

    private Element addEmptyNode(Element appointment, String name) {
        Element nameElement = appointment.getOwnerDocument().createElement(name);
        appointment.appendChild(nameElement);
        return nameElement;
    }

    private Document newDoc() throws ParserConfigurationException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factoria = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factoria.newDocumentBuilder();
        return builder.newDocument();
    }

    public static UserCalendar deserialize(Document doc) {
        UserCalendar userCalendar = new UserCalendar();
        NodeList appsElms = doc.getElementsByTagName("appointment");
        for (int i = 0; i < appsElms.getLength(); i++) {
            Element appElm = (Element) appsElms.item(i);
            String name = getNodeValue(appElm, "name");
            String lastname = getNodeValue(appElm, "lastname");
            int day = getNodeValueInt(appElm, "day");
            int month = getNodeValueInt(appElm, "month");
            int year = getNodeValueInt(appElm, "year");
            String hour = getNodeValue(appElm, "hour");
            String title = getNodeValue(appElm, "title");
            String description = getNodeValue(appElm, "description");
            String row = getNodeValue(appElm, "row");
            String column = getNodeValue(appElm, "column");

            Appointment appointment = new Appointment(hour, day, month, year, name, lastname, title, description, row,
                    column);
            userCalendar.add(appointment);
        }
        return userCalendar;
    }

    private static String getNodeValue(Element appElm, String name) {
        String strVal = null;
        NodeList nl = appElm.getElementsByTagName(name);
        if (nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0) {
            strVal = nl.item(0).getTextContent();
        }
        return strVal;
    }

    private static int getNodeValueInt(Element appElm, String name) {
        String str = getNodeValue(appElm, name);
        return str == null ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(str);
    }
}
```

#### Service

```java
public class UserCalendarService {

    public UserCalendar load() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        File file = new File("Appointments.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(file);
        return UserCalendar.deserialize(doc);
    }

    public void save(UserCalendar calendar) throws IOException, TransformerException, ParserConfigurationException {
        Document doc = calendar.serialize();
        TransformerFactory factoria = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = factoria.newTransformer();
        Source source = new DOMSource(doc);
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Appointments.xml");){


            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(fos);
            transformer.transform(source, result);
        }


    }


    public void add(Appointment appointment) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, TransformerException {
        UserCalendar cal = load();
        cal.add(appointment);
        save(cal);
    }

}
```

#### Usage example

```java
        // Create an appointments with 2 entity
        UserCalendar userCalendar = new UserCalendar();
        userCalendar.add(new Appointment("20:30",31,12,2019,"newYearEve","Happy New Year Party!!!","mark","zuk","1","3"));
        userCalendar.add(new Appointment("12:30",1,1,2020,"recover","Party recovery mode.","mark","zuk","2","3"));
        UserCalendarService svc = new UserCalendarService();
        svc.save(userCalendar);

// Append an entity to an existing appointment file
        svc.add(new Appointment("8:30",7,1,2020,"work","Back to work","mark","zuk","2","3"));
```